# PostGIS 2.5 error while compiling from source on Ubuntu Server 18.04

Tags: postgis, ubuntu, proj

I'm compiling PostGIS 2.5 from source on Ubuntu Server 18.04

The server had no internet connection due to client requirements, so I've been following *PostGIS 2.5.1dev Manual, 2.4. Compiling and Install from Source: Detailed* Steps ( https://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.5/postgis_installation.html#PGInstall ).

It's required to install (compile from source) the next packages:

1. Proj4 reprojection library, version 4.9.0 or greater.
2. GEOS geometry library, version 3.5 or greater.
3. LibXML2, version 2.5.x or higher.
4. JSON-C, version 0.9 or higher.
5. GDAL, version 1.8 or higher.

Everything works fine after typical compiling instructions:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

Then I compile PostGIS again with typical instructions:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

In order to check if everything is working, I connect to my DB:

```
sudo -u postgres psql postgres
postgres=# \c testdb
testdb=# \CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```

And then... 
**PostGIS ERROR: could not load library "/usr/lib/postgresql/10/lib/postgis-2.5.so": libproj.so.13: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.**

As far as I understand, the problem is with libproj so I've compiled again, but had no success.

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

If you did not install postgis in /usr, then this error is normal.

You need to configure ldconfig to link you compiled libs.
You could export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/postgres or /usr/local (see in the makefile)
or you can permanently add a config file in /etc/ld.conf.so.d/   with the path of your libs before calling 'sudo ldconfig'.

The best way is that you find where is this libproj.so; may be you just need a symlink to get postgres to find it.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! It worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I pass you a post, it is in Spanish, but it will be useful to install PostGIS 2.5 in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS [post](https://proyectosbeta.net/2018/10/postgis-2-5-en-ubuntu-bionic-beaver-18-04-lts/)

Comment: Thanks!! Very useful post, it explains a lot about the configuration.